# Combobox loading text with invisible linefeed (\r) or newline (\n)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, combobox, visual-studio-2017

I'm using c#, visual studio 2017, winforms and
I'm having a problem with a combobox which is loading some text from a text file and when I select another line of text from the combobox, a linefeed (\r) is added there, and it looks like it's somewhat invisible or better saying, it looks like a newline (\n).

This is the combobox in question and the invisible linefeed (\r).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhymg.png

When I debug the application I can see \r added after that line of text.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/km4F3.png

I've tried to use Encoding.Unicode when saving the text, but to no avail.

```
//This is how I save text to a file
private void SaveVarNameToFile()
{
    using (var writer = File.AppendText("savedVarName.txt"))
    {
        writer.Write(comboBox1.Text, Encoding.Unicode);
    }
}

//This is how I load the text to combobox
private void LoadStrTextFromFile(string fileName, ComboBox cb)
{
   if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            return;

   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
   {
      string x = reader.ReadToEnd();
      string[] y = x.Split('\n');
      foreach (string s in y)
      {
         cb.Items.Add(s);
      }
      reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Contents of the text file:

```
BOOST_ROOT
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS
OS
PROCESSOR_LEVEL
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to remove that pesky little thing. Perhaps there's an easy fix.
If someone can help me find a way or remove it or modify the code so it won't load the \r, I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: You can just use `File.ReadLines(filename)`. `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename)) cb.Items.Add(line);`

Comment: please add the contents of the text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses \r\n to mark the end of a line of text. *NIX and Macs use different markers. You can see how different systems handle this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Instead of handling the splitting of lines manually, I recommend using built-in functionality for doing this (i.e. [File.ReadLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
private void LoadStrTextFromFile(string fileName, ComboBox cb)
{
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        return;

    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
        cb.Items.Add(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach

```
    // remember to use double back slash on the path
    string[] text  = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test.txt").Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)).Distinct().ToArray(); // read the file into a string array with removing the duplicates and empty lines
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(text); // finally fill in the combobox with the array
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your way of doing it. I will try it.